# Ensembles Idiomatic app not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ensembles

Is the Ensembles example app, Idiomatic, supposed to work without having to configure it or link it to libraries like dropbox? When trying to start it I get this :

```
[...] Ensembles Basic Support/Ensembles 2.2/Source Code/Ensembles/Framework/Extensions/
CDEDropboxSyncCloudFileSystem.h:13:9: 'Dropbox/Dropbox.h' file not found
```

Does anyone know how to get it working? (I'm using Ensembles 2.2)

Comment: You do need to have the Dropbox framework, but it should be included in the Vendor folder. Do you have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when I was adding the DropboxSync framework, I accidentally included a full path, rather than a relative path, in the frameworks search path.

You can easily fix it by selecting the Idiomatic iOS target, going to Build Settings, locating the framework search path setting. Change it to `$(SRCROOT)/../../Vendor/DropboxSyncSDK/iOS`

[image]